# Link in dialog closes dialog and doesn't do anything else in JqueryMobile

Tags: dialog, hyperlink, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with links in dialog page. In fact, these links don't work, they close dialog page and do anything else. I look the demo at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html and links in dialog don't work either.

Have you any idea to correct that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this.

But the javascript provided by this link : http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/ but this file is not complete (for example, it doesn't contain data-role="field-contain").

But like said Naugtur, there's good news : 
I found on the internet the solution :
     download the version uncompressed of this file : jquery-mobile-1.0a2.js at jquerymobile.com and modify this file :

```
$.widget( "mobile.dialog", $.mobile.widget, {
   $closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Close</a>');
   $el.delegate("a, submit", "click submit", function(e){
      if( e.type == "click" && ( $(e.target).closest('[data-back]') || $(e.target).closest($closeBtn) ) ){         
     self.close();
     return false;
      }
$.mobile.activePage = this.element;         
});
```

Replace the line :  `if( e.type == "click" && ( $(e.target).closest('[data-back]') || $(e.target).closest($closeBtn) ) ){`
by :  `if( e.type == "click" && ( $(e.target).closest('[data-back]')[0] || this==$closeBtn[0] ) ){`

and :  `$.mobile.activePage = this.element;`
by :  `$.mobile.activePage = self.element;`

This works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Link in the demo points back to the page, so it might work... But when I change href with firebug it does the same. Looks like you found a bug in jqm alpha2.

But there's good news. The bug is fixed. See:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/#pages/docs-dialogs.html

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs is a version of docs generated from the repository (daily or so)